# Count the working days of an employee generating 1 2..31 days and the time will only appear to those days

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, while-loop, switch-statement

Dim cmd As OdbcCommand = New OdbcCommand("SELECT distinct checktime,format(CHECKTIME,'Short Date') as adlaws, format(CHECKTIME,'ampm') as formatz,checktype " & _
                                                 "from CHECKINOUT where userid=" & Label6.Text & " and checktime between #" & FormatDateTime(DateTimePicker1.Value, DateFormat.ShortDate) & _
                                                 "# and #" & FormatDateTime(DateTimePicker2.Value, DateFormat.ShortDate) & "#", con)

```
    Try
        Dim dr As OdbcDataReader
        ListView1.Items.Clear()
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader


        MsgBox(i & " " & adlawan)
        Do While dr.Read()



            Dim Str1 As String = dr.Item("adlaws").ToString
            Dim Str2 As String = dr.Item("formatz").ToString
            Dim Str3 As String = dr.Item("checktype").ToString

            sLog = FormatDateTime(dr.Item("CHECKTIME").ToString, DateFormat.ShortDate)
            sTime = FormatDateTime(dr.Item("CHECKTIME").ToString, DateFormat.ShortTime)


            adlawan = Val(Mid(sLog, 3, 2))

            ' MsgBox(i & " " & adlawan)

            ' If adlawan = i Then
            'lv = ListView1.Items.Add(adlawan)
            Select Case Str3

                Case "I"

                    If Val(Mid(sTime, 1, 2)) > 3 And Val(Mid(sTime, 1, 2)) < 10 Then
                        lv = ListView1.Items.Add(adlawan)
                        a = FormatDateTime(dr.Item("CHECKTIME").ToString, DateFormat.ShortTime)
                        lv.SubItems.Add(a)
                    Else
                        d = FormatDateTime(dr.Item("CHECKTIME").ToString, DateFormat.ShortTime)
                        lv.SubItems.Add(d)
                    End If
                Case "O"
                    If Val(Mid(sTime, 1, 2)) > 10 And Val(Mid(sTime, 1, 2)) < 17 Then
                        b = FormatDateTime(dr.Item("CHECKTIME").ToString, DateFormat.ShortTime)
                        lv.SubItems.Add(b)
                    Else
                        c = FormatDateTime(dr.Item("CHECKTIME").ToString, DateFormat.ShortTime)
                        lv.SubItems.Add(c)
                    End If

            End Select
```

adlawan = adlawan + 1

```
        Loop


        con.Close()
    Catch oe As OdbcException
        MsgBox(oe.Message)
    End Try
```